# Openvswitch Installation Issue

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openvswitch

I am trying to install openvswitch on my ubuntu 12.04 Machine for KVM.

But it is showing

```
"Module has probably not been built for this kernel"
```

tried  "**module-assistant auto-install openvswitch-datapath**" which returned "

```
Version 1.4.0-1ubuntu1.5 of openvswitch-datapath-module-3.2.0-23-generic already installed, skipping.
```

Using:

kernel 3.2.0-23-generic, Ubuntu 12.04

**lsmod|brcom**  showing nothing

How can i fix datapath module issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove default bridge

```
rmmod bridge
```

Enable Module brcompat

```
modprobe brcompat_mod
```

Check

```
lsmod|grep brcompat
```

restart ovs

```
service openvswitch-switch start
```

If everything is fine try adding interface